# Navigation drawer - botão voltar

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou tentando fazer com que o botão *back* ou voltar do android mantenha a sequencia de fragments que estou renderizando conforme opção escolhida no meu menu lateral (Navigation Drawer), porém não estou conseguindo, ele sempre fecha o app quando clico em voltar e não retorna pro fragment anterior onde estava. Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            myFragment = new SliderFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_program:
            myFragment = new ProgramFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_ticket:
            myFragment = new TicketFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_togo:
            myFragment = new HowtogoFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_map:
            myFragment = new MapFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_social:
            myFragment = new SocialFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_festival:
            myFragment = new FestivalFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_contact:
            myFragment = new ContactFragment();
            break;
    }

    setTitle(item.getTitle(););

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, myFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

    return true;
}
```

E no estou pegando o click do botão voltar assim:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Como poderia fazer para manter o botão voltar normalmente? Retornando sempre para o fragment anterior, com título da action bar e item do menu selecionado correspondente?

Answer (score -1):

Em vez de FragmentManager, use o FragmentTransaction.

Exemplo:

```
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

 FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, myFragment);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
```

Comment: Qual é a diferença entre esse código e aquele que está na pergunta?

Comment: FragmentManager serve para interagir com fragments dentro de uma Activity. FragmentTransaction para um conjunto de operações com fragments, como: adicionar, remover e substituir. Nunca utilizei o FragmentManager, pois das vezes que precisei utilizei diretamente o FragmentTransaction.

Comment: Rafael, ambos os códigos estão a usar `FragmentTransaction`, a diferença é que você usa uma variável intermédia `ft` enquanto o AP usa o encadeamento de métodos(*method chaining*) para aceder directamente aos métodos de `FragmentTransaction`.